# Scrollbar in tkinter that adjusts its size automatically when the window's size changes

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, resize, scrollbar

This is my first post here in stackoverflow. I've been trying to learn Python by myself and the community here was so helpful (questions and answers). I'm trying to code a scrollbar that can adjust its size automatically when the window's size changes. I already have a working scrollbar, but it will only work when I add widgets to the canvas not when I resize the canvas.

I know adding a scrollbar in tkinter can be a bit tricky, so I was just wondering if it is possible to do so.

Thank you so much for your help.

Here's a sample of the code that I used to create the scrollbar. Please let me know if you need more details :-)

```
if sys.platform == 'darwin':
      self.canvas1 = Canvas(master, borderwidth = 0, width = 400)
else:
      self.canvas1 = Canvas(master, borderwidth = 0) 
self.canvas1.grid(row = 0 , column  = 0, sticky= N )




if sys.platform == "win32":
       self.canvas1.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", self._OnMouseWheel)
else:
       self.canvas1.bind('<Button-4>',self._OnMouseWheel)
       self.canvas1.bind('<Button-5>',self._OnMouseWheel)
self.leftframe = Frame(self.canvas1)
self.leftframe.bind("<Configure>", self.onFrameConfigure) 
self.vsb = Scrollbar(master, orient="vertical" ,activebackground = 'black', command=self.canvas1.yview)
self.canvas1.configure(yscrollcommand = self.vsb.set, height = 600)
self.vsb.grid(row = 0 , column = 0 , sticky = N+S+E)

self.canvas1.create_window((4,4), window=self.leftframe, anchor="nw", tags="self.leftframe")
```

Here are the two additional functions that I've used:

```
def onFrameConfigure(self, event):
    self.canvas1.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas1.bbox("all"))


def _OnMouseWheel(self,event):
    if sys.platform == "win32":
        self.canvas1.yview_scroll(-1*(event.delta),"units")
    else:
        if event.num == 4:
            self.canvas1.yview('scroll', -1, 'units')
        elif event.num == 5:
            self.canvas1.yview('scroll', 1, 'units')
```

Comment: your code appears to be malformed -- the line after the first else has a couple lines of code on one line.Also, you seem to be trying to use `self.leftframe` before you create it.

Comment: @BryanOakley thank you for your comment! It was a copy-paste mistake. I reorganized the code and I added the additional functions that I've used. Should I add more details?

Comment: There is  still a problem of two statements on one line after the first `else`

Comment: @BryanOakley you're absolutely right, thanks again! Sorry about that!